# Programmatically create gmail accounts using php

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Is there a php example of creating gmail accounts for a domain?  I found the below example but it does not seem to work.  I assume it is using an old SDK and not sure how to edit it to work for newer SDK or finding the old SDK that it does work with.  The topic is locked or I would just reply there.

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/yTiv0EuBKN4/3OVvj2Up-VIJ

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) within the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) to [create users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user) within your domain. This does appear to be what's being used in the post you've linked so that shouldn't be the problem. Google provides a PHP Quickstart guide [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php) which you might want to review; it's possible you've just skipped a step.

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend posting some additional details as to what you're seeing when trying to create the accounts (code, request/response, error message, etc.).